# What is the main difference between Putty to MobaXterm or XServer?

Tags: ssh, putty, x-server, mobaxterm, client-server

What is the main difference between Putty to MobaXterm or XServer?

I know they are all SSH clients (FOSS, gratis), but is there a main catergorial difference?

Answer (score 3):

You can tell this by just looking at the tagline from [MobaXterm's website](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/):

> Enhanced terminal for Windows with X11 server, tabbed SSH client, network tools and much more.

[According to its website](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html), it features:

> <sub>- Sessions management *(so does PuTTY)*
>
>    - Graphical SFTP browser
>
>    - X11 server
>
>    - Enhanced X extensions
>
>    - Multi-execution
>
>    - Embedded servers
>
>    - Embedded tools
>
>    - Remote Unix desktop (XDMCP)
>
>    - Remote Windows desktop (RDP)
>
>    - SSH gateway
>
>    - SSH tunnels (port forwarding)
>
>    - MobApt package manager
>
>    - Text Editor
>
>    - Macros support
>
>    - Passwords management
>
>    - Syntax highlighting in terminal
>
>    - Professional Customizer *(Pro Edition only)*</sub>

[image: screenshot MobaXterm]

<sub>The screenshot is from MobaXterm's demo video, hence the playback handle at the bottom. Sorry for that...</sub>

---

[PuTTY](https://putty.org/), on the other hand, is just an SSH/telnet client with a GUI. There are forks of it, such as [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Download), that offer more features.

[image: Screenshot KiTTY]

<sub>The screenshot shows 2 instances (1 already connected, 1 main window) of KiTTY, a PuTTY fork.</sub>

---

Which one you want to use is completely up to you. For quickly accessing a few dozen SSH clients with automatic user&password submission, PuTTY/KiTTY will be sufficient.

Comment: Nicely done :) 